# unexpected 'OR' (T_LOGICAL_OR)

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, if-statement, stripos

I've been trying to make an "active" state in Bootstrap, giving `li` a `class="active"` whenever it's on the specified site.

I have this script:

```
<?php if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/page1.php') !== false) OR (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/page2.php') !== false) {echo 'active';} ?>
```

It's used for a dropdown, that should have the active class whenever it's on either page1 or page2.

I get this error:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'OR' (T_LOGICAL_OR) in your code on line 1`

Does anyone know what I've done wrong here? I've tried with "OR" and "||", but none of them work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The if statement is incorrectly formatted

```
<?php if ((stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/page1.php') !== false) OR (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/page2.php') !== false)) {echo 'active';} ?>
```

Comment: The reason behind this, is because PHP will think that it is done parsing the if statement, when it ends the first parenthesis started after the IF it self. Therefore, it expects `{` after the `)` before the `OR`

Comment: So I forgot one bracket to enclose the script?

Comment: yes, you forgot to encase it... `if ( (condition1) OR (condition2) )`

Comment: It seems like a stupid question now, but I just couldn't figure out why it wouldn't work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Everyone makes rookie mistakes at some point... especially after long periods of programming. No question is stupid, there are only stupid answers. (however, on SO, this is not entirely valid... as you need to follow the MCVE - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the brakets before and after the OR like below.

`<?php if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/page1.php') !== false OR stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/page2.php') !== false) {echo 'active';} ?>`

Comment: This is basically the same as the other answer, however, neither of you explained why... unlike my comment to the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if ((stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/page1.php') !== false) OR (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/page2.php') !== false)) echo 'active'; ?>
```

> This code works - I've tried it!

One missing set of brackets and one superflous set.